# Python: How to speed up the process of mapping longitude and latitude data on UK map using Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I have a very large dataset (over 570K rows) as pandas dataframe. It has both the longitude and latitude column (all UK locations). So I want to draw them on the UK map and use matplotlib basemap. However, it takes too long to draw it. Is there any way to speed up the process or is there any mistake in my code?

```
for index, row in road.iterrows():
    count = row['count']
    x, y = m(row["Longitude"], row["Latitude"])
    size = count ** 2 + 3
    m.plot(x, y, 'o', markersize=size, color='#444444', alpha=0.8)
```

Comment: Don't use the index if you aren't going to use it

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1. Trim your dataset down to a smaller set to capture times and measure improvements.
2. Don't use an index in your for loop if you aren't using it i.e. `for row in road.iterrows():`
3. Don't assign variables if you are only using them once in the loop.

Something like:

```
for row in road.iterrows():
    m.plot(m(row["Longitude"], row["Latitude"]),
       'o',
       markersize=(row['count'] ** 2 + 3),
       color='#444444', 
       alpha=0.8)
```

Doesn't look as pretty but should speed it up a little bit.

Then track how each change makes a difference in the performance.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to visualize about the data.

My first thought would be to make a density plot of the data (by first binning the data into a larger grid yourself and then plotting that grid with color that indicates how much stuff is in each bin).

Comment: I want to plot all the location(longitude,latitude) on the UK map instead of something like a heatmap.

Comment: Ok, what are you trying to see about the data? (With half a million locations I'm not thinking just scatter plotting them is going to tell you much?)